# Path/File name slash in C++

Tags: c, file

Hello I have a little problem in my program

```
FILE* f;
char * psz = new char[wcslen(file) + 1];
wsprintfA(psz, "%S", file);
fopen_s(&f,psz, "w+b");
char * buffer = "data\heightmap.bmp";
 fwrite(buffer,256, 1, f);
fclose(f); 

//later in another class:
FILE* f;
char * bufer;
fopen_s(&f,"data\test.dat", "rb");
fread(buffer,256, 1, f);
fclose(f);
///buffer is "dataheightmap.bmp" not "data\heightmap.bmp" as it should be to open the file later.

FILE* f;
fopen_s(&f,buffer, "rb");
count = fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, f);
fclose(f);
```

someone can help me please.
Thanks
Window7,visual studio 2013.

Comment: Read your question....would you be able to answer that?  Rethink what it is you are asking and come back and post a question that describes your issue and what your expected outcome is and what is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you need to escape your slashes:

```
"data\heightmap.bmp"
"data\test.dat"
```

Should be:

```
"data\\heightmap.bmp"
"data\\test.dat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line: `char * buffer = "data\heightmap.bmp";`

Should be: `char * buffer = "data\\heightmap.bmp";`

The same thing goes for: `fopen_s(&f,"data\test.dat", "rb");`

It should be: `fopen_s(&f,"data\\test.dat", "rb");`

Comment: fopen_s(&f,"data\test.dat", "rb"); opens the file but fopen_s(&f,"data\\test.dat", "rb"); doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape character '\' in C string constant. Use following statement.

char * buffer = "data\\heightmap.bmp";

Comment: char * buffer = "data\\heightmap.bmp"; it doesn't open the file because of double \\

Answer (score 0):

ok I found that when I use this before

```
case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wparam) == ID_CREATE_HEIGHTMAP){
        TCHAR szFile[_MAX_PATH] = L"";
        OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };
        ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
        ofn.hwndOwner = System->hwnd;
        ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Heightmap data File (*.hdf)\0*.hdf\0\0";
        ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;  // This will hold the file name
        ofn.lpstrDefExt = L"hdf";
        ofn.nMaxFile = _MAX_PATH;
        ofn.lpstrTitle = L"Save File";
        ofn.Flags = OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;
        GetSaveFileName(&ofn);
        if (szFile[0]!=0)
            System->Createype(3, szFile);
    }
        break;
```

it works only if I put the folder inside this folder(GetSaveFileName(&ofn)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,I add `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR`and it seems to works now.